# Getting 403 Error While Redirecting to Custom Error Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, iis, error-handling

I have a .net mvc application(standard) and trying to implement custom errorhandling using `httpErrors`  in web config.

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace" defaultResponseMode="Redirect">       
      <clear />
      <error statusCode="404" path="http://localhost/E_HealthCare_Web/Views/Error/NotFound404" responseMode="Redirect" />      
    </httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
```

although it redirect to specified path but I get a http 403 error stating **You do not have permission to view this directory or page.**  I think its an iis error but don't know how to solve it. if it needs a permission then where should I go to get the permission or should I set it up.

**EDIT**
as mentioned in the comment i tried using absolute Url and i got *localhost redirected you too many times error and i tried clearing cookies* as i tried clearing cookies but its not working and it is redirecting to the same page infinitely as you can see below.
[image: errorimage]

**Another Edit**
Thanks to @LexLi and @JennyDai i finally solved this by changing my path in web.config to to `path="http://localhost/E_HealthCare_Web/Error/NotFound404"` by using mvc's proper route URL pattern.

Comment: Read the documentation carefully, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httperrors/ It asks for an absolute URL if you choose Redirect as response mode.

Comment: @LexLi i tried that and i am getting another _localhost redirected you too many times_ error and i tried clearing cookies  but it didn't work.

Comment: 1. When you made edits, post the new `web.config` file. 2. You are working on an ASP.NET MVC web app, so you should know that accessing `.cshtml` file in URL is simply wrong. Your routing rules determine what URL patterns are valid, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs

Comment: @LexLi but what if i want to redirect to a simple view without any action methods how do i do that

Comment: "a simple view without any action methods" does not exist in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: what about error view in shared folder which mvc provides by default

Comment: One last suggestion is that you should post/accept your own answer to finish a discussion like this, not messing up question body.

Comment: thanks for suggestion should i do it for this one too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @LexLi and @JennyDai, I finally solved this by changing my path in ***web.config*** to to `path="http://localhost/E_HealthCare_Web/Error/NotFound404"` by using MVC's proper route URL pattern.